# Algorithm for sorting a "plain-list-tree-structure"

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, tree

Sorry for that subject, I didn't find a better title :-)

I have a tree structure, here's a my "node" class:

```
public class Categoria implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private List<Categoria> children = new LinkedList<Categoria>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "parent_id",
        insertable=false,
        updatable=false
    )
    private Categoria parent;

    @Transient
    private Integer depth;

    private Integer orderNumber;

... getters, setters, ....
}
```

Don't care about Hibernate/JPA annotations, there's no problem with them, just think of an ideal pojo world.

I made a recursive method which builds a "plain" List of adjacent nodes. So, imagine this tree:

```
grandfather

 |_ father

    |_ son1

    |_ son2

 |_ uncle

grandmother

 |_ mother
```

We will have a resulting List like this one (number is "depth"):
- grandfather (1)
- father (2)
- son1 (3)
- son2 (3)
- uncle (2)
- grandmother (1)
- mother (2)

All that works good.

Now I want to let my users edit nodes sorting (between same depth nodes), I mean: what if I want "son2" before "son1" in the above list?

So I tought to add a "orderNumber" property: all orderNumbers are 0 initially.
Then my user set son1's orderNumber to 99 and son2's orderNumber to 88.

The question is: **how can I rearrange the resulting list to get the sorting based on the orderNumber?**

But wait.... I only want to sort "sublists", so that sons sorting is absolutely not related to "fathers" and "uncles" sorting!

Thank you for helping us.

**EDIT:** You're all missing one thing. I did not explain myself very well. Here's an example:

- grandfather (depth:1, ordernumber:1)
- father (depth:2, ordernumber:1)
- son1 (depth:3, ordernumber:1)
- son2 (depth:3, ordernumber:2)
- uncle (depth:2, ordernumber:2)
- grandmother (depth:1, ordernumber:2)
- mother (depth:2, ordernumber:1)

Now I want to swap son1 and son2 so the resulting list will be:

- grandfather (depth:1, ordernumber:1)
- father (depth:2, ordernumber:1)
- **son2 (depth:3, ordernumber:1)**
- **son1 (depth:3, ordernumber:2)**
- uncle (depth:2, ordernumber:2)
- grandmother (depth:1, ordernumber:2)
- mother (depth:2, ordernumber:1)

How can I implement a sort / compareTo for such purpose??

Comment: fathers are sons to grandfathers? or are you basing it from a certain individual?

Comment: I have an invisible "ROOT" element, I don't put it in the resulting plain list. Fathers are sons to grandfathers. Grandfathers are brother to Grandmothers.

Comment: Remember: orderNumber is not "global", I mean, three sons can have 1,2,3 as orderNumber, two fathers can have 1,2.... how can I compare between sublists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed that:

```
private List<Categoria> getAlberoCategorie(Categoria root, int profondita) {
        List<Categoria> tmpList = new ArrayList<Categoria>();
        root.setProfondita(profondita);
        if ( root.getParent() != null ) {
            Hibernate.initialize(root.getTraduzioni());
            tmpList.add(root);
        }       

        List<Categoria> children = root.getChildren();
        Collections.sort(children, new Comparator<Categoria>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Categoria o1, Categoria o2) {
                return o1.getOrdinamento().compareTo(o2.getOrdinamento());
            }
        });

        if (!children.isEmpty()) {
            profondita++;
            for (Categoria figlia : children) {
                List<Categoria> discendenza = getAlberoCategorie(figlia,profondita);                
                tmpList.addAll(discendenza);
            }
        }       
        return tmpList;
    }
```

Thank you all anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Let Categoria implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Create a custom compareTo implementation, where you order by depth and on ties your additional OrderNumber attribute decides. That would work in any sortable collection.

But depending on the problem you are solving with that tree-structure it may be more suitable to implement a custom iterator for your tree instead of recursively creating "list snapshots" ?

Comment: Can you explain yourself better? I can't see how to implement compareTo() I mean... I don't want my "depth 1" elements to be all side-by-side

Comment: I see the problem now. I think there is no simple way to solve this problem by sorting, as it requires knowledge about the whole list instead of only two elements like a compareTo() method. Do you absolutely have to use a list and rearrange the list after its creation? When you are creating the list, you could sort the children array by their orderNumber. Maybe you can tell more about the requirements? As I said in my answer, you should think about exposing your tree as the datastructure itself instead of copying it into a plain list.

Comment: Thank you @Pyranja you're the one who did understand! I ended up sorting while building my list (I do need a list, to build a <h:datatable> in JSF, eg)... How? I have a recursive function who takes "children" at a certain point: I simply sort the "children" list before pass it again to the same function. Doing it was simpler  than explain :)

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the sublists explicit with Collections.sort() and the appropiate comparator.

If the sorting is known when creating the lists you could use a ordered set like TreeSet with an comparator instead of LinkedList. So the items will be sorted when inserting.

Answer (score 1):

I would make your class implements `Comparable` and in the `compareTo` method I would use the fields `depth` and `orderNumber` to compute the order. Having done this, you can use Collectoins.sort() to sort your list.

Example code:

```
public class Categoria implements Serializable, Comparable<Categoria> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // ... omitting other fields/annotations/getters/setters

    private Integer depth;

    private Integer orderNumber;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Categoria other) {
        if (depth < other.depth)
            return -1;
        if (depth > other.depth)
            return 1;
        // if we get here the two objects have the same depth, so we compare 
        // based on orderNumber
        if (orderNumber < other.orderNumber)
            return -1;
        if (orderNumber > other.orderNumber)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

}
```